# Group according to cumulative sums

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping, cumsum

I want to make groups according to the accumulated sum. in my tiny example, the two first numbers in the column value sums to exactly 100 and is group A. The three next numbers sum to less than 100 and go to group B, while the last number exceeds 100 and gets its own group C - and so forth.

```
input <- data.frame(id=c(1:6),
                   value =c(99, 1,  33, 33, 33, 150))
input

desired_output <- data.frame(id=c(1:6),
              value =c(99, 1,  33, 33, 33, 150),
              group= c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C"))

desired_output
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible one-liners, with `purrr::accumulate` and with `MESS::cumsumbinning`:

**`purrr::accumulate`**

```r
library(tidyverse)
group_by(input, grp = LETTERS[cumsum(value == accumulate(value, ~ ifelse(.x + .y <= 100, .x + .y, .y)))])
```

**`MESS::cumsumbinning`**

```r
library(dplyr)
group_by(input, grp = LETTERS[MESS::cumsumbinning(value, 100)])
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   grp [3]
     id value grp  
  <int> <dbl> <chr>
1     1    99 A    
2     2     1 A    
3     3    33 B    
4     4    33 B    
5     5    33 B    
6     6   150 C
```

Comment: Thank you for the solutions Meal! Both work fine. I was unaware of the MESS::cumsumbinning function, but your dplyr solution works beautifully.

Comment: a great solution! please tell me what it means `.y` in the formula?

Answer (score 1):

```r
desired_output <- data.frame(id=c(1:6),
                             value =c(99, 1,  33, 33, 33, 150),
                             group= c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C"))

library(tidyverse)

desired_output %>% 
  group_by(grp_new = cumsum(value - 1) %/% 100) %>% 
  mutate(grp_new = LETTERS[cur_group_id()]) %>% 
  ungroup() 
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>      id value group grp_new
#>   <int> <dbl> <chr> <chr>  
#> 1     1    99 A     A      
#> 2     2     1 A     A      
#> 3     3    33 B     B      
#> 4     4    33 B     B      
#> 5     5    33 B     B      
#> 6     6   150 C     C
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This method does not work. Wrong groups will be assigned. Eg `c(70,20,50,20,35)` Not that the first 2 ie `70, 20` sums to less than 100, then the next two sums to less than 100. From this we should have 3 groups. But using cumsum, it will show this to only have two groups which is incorrect

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution only produces NA for me. I have not tried to find the problem yet, but I have a look at it later. But thank you for the ideas anyway.